# Ghostscript not working with Popen or check_output

Tags: python

I have the following ghostscript command to crop the top of a pdf file. If I run it from CLI, there is no issue :

```
gs -q -dNOPAUSE -dBATCH -r300 -sCompression=lzw -dDownScaleFactor=1 -dDownScaleFactor=1 -sDEVICE=tiff32nc -dFirstPage=1 -dLastPage=1 -sOutputFile=/home/nathan/PycharmProjects/oc_invoices_flask/bin/data/tmp/tmp38v2hugr/tmpo70tgixc_header.tiff /home/nathan/PycharmProjects/oc_invoices_flask/4635913834.pdf
```

I need to run this command from a python program. I try this, but there is no TIFF file created...

```
args = [
    "gs", "-q", "-dNOPAUSE", '-dBATCH',
    "-r" + str(self.resolution), "-sCompression=lzw",
    "-dDownScaleFactor=1", "-dDownScaleFactor=1",
    "-sDEVICE=tiff32nc", "-dFirstPage=1", "-dLastPage=1",
    "-sOutputFile=" + self.jpgName_tiff_header,
    "-dDEVICEHEIGHTPOINTS=350", "-dFIXEDMEDIA",
    "-c '<</PageOffset [0 500]>> setpagedevice'",
    pdfName
]
output = Popen(args, stdout = sys.stdout, stderr = sys.stderr)
```

I also try with this lib : https://pypi.org/project/ghostscript/ using the same arguments. It's working but it was cropping the bottom of the PDF instead of the header...

Any ideas ?

Thanks

Comment: You really need to see if Ghostscript gave you any messages on stdout or stderr. If it did, these will give you clues, you should also drop -q at this point since you want all the feedback you can get. If you got nothing back (after removing -q) then Ghostscript didn't execute. I don't know what error handling Python might have, but you should check for errors returned. My bet woudl be a missing path, have you tried specifying a fill path to gs ?

Comment: In addition, your command line has DownScaleFactor tiwce, and setting it to 1 has no effect anyway. You've set the media height, but not the media width, is that intentional ? This isn't really a Ghostscript question, since GS clearly works correctly as per the command line so I've removed the Ghostscript tag.

Comment: Well, with Popen I finally have something working. But, I want to crop the PDF to keep only the top, but it gaves me the bottom... If I launch manually, I have the top of the PDF...

Comment: And yes the media width not set is intentionnal

Comment: If you are getting different results when running from the command line and using Popen, then there must be some difference in the invocation (or, just possibly, the version of Ghostscript). And indeed, a cursory glance at the two shows that your command line lacks the PageOffset, which moves the origin from the lower left to 0, 500. I'd imagine that would be the reason. Your command line also lacks the DEVICHEIGHTPOINTS and FIXEDMEDIA switches. Your Popen invocation uses -c but does not terminate it with -f before the input filename, so the input file name will be treated as PostScript.